# Can I get Only US zipcodes from geonames JSON response?

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete, geonames

Hi I am Using jquery UI autocomplete plugin for zipcode field.

jQuery UI autocomplete plugin uses geonames.org's JSON response.

Here is my code to get response :-

```
jQuery( "#"+prefix+"_zip" ).autocomplete({

        source: function( request, response ) {
            jQuery.ajax({
                url: "http://ws.geonames.org/postalCodeSearchJSON",
                dataType: "jsonp",
                data: {
                    style: "full",
                    maxRows: 12,
                    postalcode_startsWith: request.term
                },
                success: function( data ) {

                    response( jQuery.map( data.postalCodes, function( item ) {
                        return {
                            label: item.placeName + (item.adminCode1 ? ", " + item.adminCode1 : "") + ", " + item.postalCode + ", "+item.countryCode,
                            value: item.postalCode
                        }
                    }));
                                        jQuery('.ui-autocomplete').css('width', '188px');
                }
            });
        }
```

For now, when put my cursor in zipcode field and enter any zipcode then it suggest me a autocomplete list for entered no or we can say jQuery plugin shows me relative values for the code that I have Entered.

Now I have one custom requirement, I want to get JSON response for US zipcodes only.

I mean when enter any value in zipcode field then it should show US related zipcode as autocomplete list.

Can any one tell me that how to get only US zipcodes JSON response from geonames.org ??

Comment: Can you share any code which you are using to communicate with the geonames service in JS so we can help with your issue?

Comment: Sure Suhail I will Edit the question with my code

Comment: @Suhail Hey I have uploaded the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your url can pass the country as a parameter,

e.g. Mexico
http://ws.geonames.org/searchJSON?&country=MX

United States
http://ws.geonames.org/searchJSON?&country=US

Something also cool is if you want to have the api return all cities in Mexico and the United states you can do this,

http://ws.geonames.org/searchJSON?&country=US,MX&username=tpassolano

NOTE: geonames now requires a username, updated api call

Hope this helps!

Comment: geonames supports https too.

Answer (score 0):

You can modify your request slightly and add the option for country:

```
jQuery("#"+prefix+"_zip").autocomplete({
    source: function( request, response ) {
        jQuery.ajax({
            url: "http://ws.geonames.org/postalCodeSearchJSON",
            dataType: "jsonp",
            data: {
                style: "full",
                maxRows: 12,
                postalcode_startsWith: request.term,
                country: "US"
            },
            success: function( data ) {
                response( jQuery.map( data.postalCodes, function( item ) {
                    return {
                        label: item.placeName + (item.adminCode1 ? ", " + item.adminCode1 : "") + ", " + item.postalCode + ", "+item.countryCode,
                        value: item.postalCode
                    }
                }));
                jQuery('.ui-autocomplete').css('width', '188px');
            }
        });
    }
});
```

All the options for Postal Code Search are listed on the [GeoNames Web Services Documentation](http://www.geonames.org/export/web-services.html)